# How to link to apps on the app store

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I am creating a free version of my iPhone game. I want to have a button inside the free version that takes people to the paid version in the app store. If I use a standard link

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=300136119&mt=8

the iPhone opens Safari first, and then the app store. I have used other apps that open the app store directly, so I know it is possible.

Any ideas? What is the URL Scheme for the app store?

Comment: For SWIFT 3.X and localized apps this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41765175/3143890

Answer (score 822, accepted):

**Edited on 2016-02-02**

Starting from iOS 6 [SKStoreProductViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/index.html) class was introduced. You can link an app without leaving your app. Code snippet in **Swift 3.x/2.x** and **Objective-C** is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32008404/1151916).

> A [SKStoreProductViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/index.html) object presents a store that allows the
> user to purchase other media from the App Store. For example, your app
> might display the store to allow the user to purchase another app.

---

From [News and Announcement For Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01062010a).

> Drive Customers Directly to Your App
> on the App Store with iTunes Links
> With iTunes links you can provide your
> customers with an easy way to access
> your apps on the App Store directly
> from your website or marketing
> campaigns. Creating an iTunes link is
> simple and can be made to direct
> customers to either a single app, all
> your apps, or to a specific app with
> your company name specified.
>
> To send customers to a specific
> application:
> http://itunes.com/apps/appname
>
> To send
> customers to a list of apps you have
> on the App Store:
> http://itunes.com/apps/developername
>
> To send customers to a specific app
> with your company name included in the
> URL:
> http://itunes.com/apps/developername/appname

---

**Additional notes:**

You can replace `http://` with `itms://` or `itms-apps://` to avoid redirects.

**Please note** that `itms://` will send the user to the **iTunes store** and `itms-apps://` with send them to the **App Store!**

For info on naming, see Apple QA1633:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1633/_index.html.

**Edit (as of January 2015):**

itunes.com/apps links should be updated to appstore.com/apps.  See QA1633 above, which has been updated. A new [QA1629](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1629/_index.html) suggests these steps and code for launching the store from an app:

1. Launch iTunes on your computer.
2. Search for the item you want to link to.
3. Right-click or control-click on the item's name in iTunes, then choose "Copy iTunes Store URL" from the pop-up menu.
4. In your application, create an `NSURL` object with the copied iTunes URL, then pass this object to `UIApplication`' s `openURL`: method to open your item in the App Store.

Sample code:

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"itms://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

iOS10+:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
   let urlStr = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8"
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: urlStr)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlStr)!)
    }
```

Comment: A tip is to use itms:// instead of http://, then it'll open in the app store directly. On the iPhone, it will make 2 (!) redirects when using http, and 1 when using itms. When using the older phobos links (see above), there are 0 redirects. Use the id from iTunes Connect if using phobos links. You can choose to submit an app without including the binary. This way you will get the id before you submit the actual binary. I haven't tried this, but I've heard it works.

Comment: Is there a way to link like this and still maintain affiliate status?

Comment: I'm not sure. You might want to ask this as a separate question, as you are likely to get more answers that way.

Comment: What if your app name contains spaces? Would that be replaced by underscores in the link?

Comment: See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1633/_index.html (White space should just be removed.)

Comment: The link in this post is broken; the content looks like it came from a news snippet posted on 1/6/2010.  Nathan S. has a better link.

Comment: Except...what is the correct value to use for `appname`?  Is it the app's "Bundle Display Name"?  Is it case-insensitive?  How are blank spaces handled, etc.?

Comment: @aroth, the correct name for appname is the name that you have given (or intend to do so) in iTunesConnect when uploading the app for the first time. Therefore you may not be able to test the link before the app is finally in the store. To overcome that I used a link to my app home page from where I lead via link to the store (and provided other information of course). With the first update of my app I linked directly to the store.

Comment: This should be tested on a real device.

Comment: @quano Using the full itunes.apple.com URL with http (instead of itunes.com) also opens the app store directly.

Comment: @AndrewHershberger But what quano is saying is that using itms reduces the number of redirects, therefore making it a better experience for the user.

Comment: This SHOULD be tested on a real device, yes! I struggled with nothing happening for about an hour before plugging the iPad in and testing it there. Geh.

Comment: @bagusflyer See the link to QA1633, it has all the necessary details on naming.

Comment: @GMsoF, this was long ago, and I'm not sure whether or not the redirects still apply. Anyway, you can find a phobos link below. http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=300136119&mt=8 . Simply change the id to your app id.

Comment: Google shows the link "Will be visible at..." when uploading to Google Play. And the reason Apple doesn't show this link when uploading is...? >:( It's left to the insecurity of googling news, blog and forum posts that could be old and invalid. At least Nathan S. is helpful, so +1 for that!

Comment: http://itunes.com/apps/developername is not working for me.Can we open and show all the apps uploaded by the developer in one page?

Comment: @Imran I assume you're replacing "developername" with your developer name? See the linked QA1633 for information about how to get the proper developer name.

Comment: Thanks Nathan but I am unable to get it.Can you please tell me whether this functionality is working in the latest update.

Comment: suppose my developer name is Imran then I am passing...http://appstore.com/imran...So this is valid one but its not working.

Comment: @Imran I suggest asking this in a separate question, linking back to this question for reference.

Comment: My app name has spaces. How do I put my app name at the end of the link ?? @HermannKlecker

Comment: @WowBow See the comment above -- white spaces are removed.

Comment: Is it acceptable to use the app's ID only, e.g. itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id123456789?mt=8 The link generator uses the 'app store name', which I plan to change on the next update, but it's not set yet...

Comment: I recommend using the path with developername preceding the appname; that way if your app name changes the user will still be taken to the list of developer apps.

Comment: tried the update on the simulator and I get an error in the browser page "address invalid"

Comment: If you use itms: It will not show you the option to update if there is an update available. Use itms-apps:// or https:// instead.

Comment: To search the link, Apple has now an interface much better and easier:
https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/

Comment: On iOS. `itms` opens itunes. while `itms-apps` opens the App Store. This is a key difference if prompting users to update! (iOS 10)

Comment: Code snippets in [Swift and objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32008404/1151916)

Comment: The highly-rated comment says to use `itms://`... but that opens the iTunes app, not the App Store app! Use `itms-apps://` instead.

Comment: Note that any links given here do not work in the simulator (iOS 11 beta3), but works on the device (iOS 10.3).

Comment: Currently (iOS 11) to open the developer's page you need to use a link similar to this one: itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/developer/johndoe/id123456789

Comment: Note that `SKStoreProductViewController` is extremely slow on iOS 12 devices. It sometimes takes over 10 seconds for me to load the product page, so I wouldn't recommend using that class on iOS 12 to avoid losing all the impatient users. (see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/107618)

Comment: how to open in App Store instead of iTunes Store? Also it's better not include `us` in the link.

Comment: and iTunes Store app can be deleted by a user

Comment: please also see `https://tools.applemediaservices.com/app-store/`

Answer (score 373):

If you want to open an app directly to the App Store, you should use:

itms-apps://...

This way it will directly open the App Store app in the device, instead of going to iTunes first, then only open the App Store (when using just itms://)

---

EDIT: APR, 2017.
itms-apps:// actually works again in iOS10. I tested it.

EDIT: APR, 2013.
This no longer works in iOS5 and above. Just use

```
https://itunes.apple.com/app/id378458261
```

and there are no more redirects.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary any longer. I use http in my app and it goes straight to the App Store app.

Comment: @PEZ As of today, I'm seeing two redirects when using http://... The answer works perfectly for me - itms-apps://... directly opens the App Store app on device, without any redirects.

Comment: I admit, i didn't trace the requests. =) I'll change to imts-apps too now.

Comment: helps a bunch, thanks. fwiw, using just "itms:" on ipad2/ios 4 i get a redirect, and with "itms-apps:" i don't.

Comment: Rocotilos, are you sure this no longer works? Can you post a link?

Comment: Can we open and show all the apps uploaded by the developer in one page?

Comment: It does indeed help.  I needed this specific answer because we've moved to a universal app.  We need to avoid reference to the app name in the url (because it is changing) while pointing the user to the very app that will be replaced by the universal app.

Comment: On iOS.  `itms` opens itunes. while `itms-apps` opens the App Store.  This is a key difference if prompting users to update! (iOS 10)

Comment: `itms` is valid right now, however, `itms-apps` or `itms-apps` is invalid. For example, `itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id375380948` is reported as invalid by safari on any iOS 10 device. @mcm

Comment: `itms-apps` opens the App Store app for me via `openURL:` in iOS 10.2. Seems to be no issue.

Comment: Since 10.3 this method works but it have to pass through an intermediate display popup 'open this URL with app store'? Reference: https://blog.branch.io/the-problem-with-apple-app-store-redirects-on-safari-ios-10-3/

Comment: Thanks for this.. It works like a play store link :)

Comment: @DawnSong it's not about Safari, it's about app you develop

Comment: Basic guidelines https://www.whatmattered.com/publishing-mobile-apps-on-app-store-google-play/

Answer (score 63):

Starting from iOS 6 right way to do it by using **SKStoreProductViewController** class.

**Swift 5.x**:

```
func openStoreProductWithiTunesItemIdentifier(_ identifier: String) {
    let storeViewController = SKStoreProductViewController()
    storeViewController.delegate = self

    let parameters = [ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : identifier]
    storeViewController.loadProduct(withParameters: parameters) { [weak self] (loaded, error) -> Void in
        if loaded {
            // Parent class of self is UIViewContorller
            self?.present(storeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
private func productViewControllerDidFinish(viewController: SKStoreProductViewController) {
    viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
// Usage:
openStoreProductWithiTunesItemIdentifier("1234567")
```

**Swift 3.x**:

```
func openStoreProductWithiTunesItemIdentifier(identifier: String) {
    let storeViewController = SKStoreProductViewController()
    storeViewController.delegate = self

    let parameters = [ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : identifier]
    storeViewController.loadProduct(withParameters: parameters) { [weak self] (loaded, error) -> Void in
        if loaded {
            // Parent class of self is UIViewContorller
            self?.present(storeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

func productViewControllerDidFinish(_ viewController: SKStoreProductViewController) {
    viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
// Usage:
openStoreProductWithiTunesItemIdentifier(identifier: "13432")
```

> You can get the app's itunes item identifier like this: (instead of a static one)

**Swift 3.2**

```
var appID: String = infoDictionary["CFBundleIdentifier"]
var url = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=\(appID)")
var data = Data(contentsOf: url!)
var lookup = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [AnyHashable: Any]
var appITunesItemIdentifier = lookup["results"][0]["trackId"] as? String
openStoreProductViewController(withITunesItemIdentifier: Int(appITunesItemIdentifier!) ?? 0)
```

**Swift 2.x**:

```
func openStoreProductWithiTunesItemIdentifier(identifier: String) {
    let storeViewController = SKStoreProductViewController()
    storeViewController.delegate = self

    let parameters = [ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : identifier]
    storeViewController.loadProductWithParameters(parameters) { [weak self] (loaded, error) -> Void in
        if loaded {
            // Parent class of self is UIViewContorller
            self?.presentViewController(storeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

func productViewControllerDidFinish(viewController: SKStoreProductViewController) {
    viewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
// Usage
openStoreProductWithiTunesItemIdentifier("2321354")
```

---

**objective-C**:

```
static NSInteger const kAppITunesItemIdentifier = 324684580;
[self openStoreProductViewControllerWithITunesItemIdentifier:kAppITunesItemIdentifier];

- (void)openStoreProductViewControllerWithITunesItemIdentifier:(NSInteger)iTunesItemIdentifier {
    SKStoreProductViewController *storeViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];

    storeViewController.delegate = self;

    NSNumber *identifier = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:iTunesItemIdentifier];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:identifier };
    UIViewController *viewController = self.window.rootViewController;
    [storeViewController loadProductWithParameters:parameters
                                   completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
                                       if (result)
                                           [viewController presentViewController:storeViewController
                                                              animated:YES
                                                            completion:nil];
                                       else NSLog(@"SKStoreProductViewController: %@", error);
                                   }];

    [storeViewController release];
}

#pragma mark - SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate

- (void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController *)viewController {
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

> You can get `kAppITunesItemIdentifier` (app's itunes item identifier) like this: (instead of a static one)

```
NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString* appID = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=%@", appID]];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary* lookup = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSString * appITunesItemIdentifier =  lookup[@"results"][0][@"trackId"]; 
    [self openStoreProductViewControllerWithITunesItemIdentifier:[appITunesItemIdentifier intValue]];
```

Comment: in swift don't forget to import and delegate:

import StoreKit

class RateMeViewController: UIViewController, SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate {

Comment: This still works, however when you go and click Write a Review, it does not work. You have to click the Store button in the top corner and then click Write a Review. Anyone know a workaround??

Comment: "Write a review" tries to open another modal and fails, probably because you're already presenting in modal. But Apple forces it. So seems there is no proper way to make reviews work. rendering this whole concept void.

Comment: That json not always returning data and returns count zero sometimes. Not reliable to get app id before submission.

Answer (score 43):

Apple just announced the appstore.com urls.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html

> There are three types of App Store Short Links, in two forms, one for iOS apps, another for Mac Apps:
>
> ### Company Name
>
> iOS: http://appstore.com/ for example, http://appstore.com/apple
>
> Mac: http://appstore.com/mac/ for example, http://appstore.com/mac/apple
>
> ### App Name
>
> iOS: http://appstore.com/ for example, http://appstore.com/keynote
>
> Mac: http://appstore.com/mac/ for example, http://appstore.com/mac/keynote
>
> ### App by Company
>
> iOS: http://appstore.com// for example, http://appstore.com/apple/keynote
>
> Mac: http://appstore.com/mac// for example, http://appstore.com/mac/apple/keynote
>
> Most companies and apps have a canonical App Store Short Link. This canonical URL is created by changing or removing certain characters (many of which are illegal or have special meaning in a URL (for example, "&")).
>
> ### To create an App Store Short Link, apply the following rules to your company or app name:
>
> Remove all whitespace
>
> Convert all characters to lower-case
>
> Remove all copyright (©), trademark (™) and registered mark (®) symbols
>
> Replace ampersands ("&") with "and"
>
> Remove most punctuation (See Listing 2 for the set)
>
> Replace accented and other "decorated" characters (ü, å, etc.) with their elemental character (u, a, etc.)
>
> Leave all other characters as-is.
>
> Listing 2  Punctuation characters that must be removed.
>
> !¡"#$%'()*+,-./:;<=>¿?@[]^_`{|}~
>
> Below are some examples to demonstrate the conversion that takes place.
>
> ### App Store
>
> ### Company Name examples
>
> Gameloft => http://appstore.com/gameloft
>
> Activision Publishing, Inc. => http://appstore.com/activisionpublishinginc
>
> Chen's Photography & Software => http://appstore.com/chensphotographyandsoftware
>
> ### App Name examples
>
> Ocarina => http://appstore.com/ocarina
>
> Where’s My Perry? => http://appstore.com/wheresmyperry
>
> Brain Challenge™ => http://appstore.com/brainchallenge

Comment: this is actually the only thing that still works reliable for mac store at least

Comment: Good to know about this, but unfortunately on iOS this redirects through Safari (and gives an ugly "Cannot Verify Server Identity" message).

Comment: NO. Read this - "These App Store Short Links are provided as a convenience and are not guaranteed to link to a particular app or company." So basically it is randomly given.

Answer (score 42):

## For summer 2015 onwards ...

```
-(IBAction)clickedUpdate
{
    NSString *simple = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1234567890";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:simple]];
}
```

replace 'id1234567890' with 'id' and 'your ten digit number'

1. This works perfectly on **all devices**.
2. It does go **straight to** the app store, no redirects.
3. Is OK for all **national stores**.
4. It's true you should **move to using** `loadProductWithParameters`, **but** if the purpose of the link is to update the app you are actually inside of: it's possibly better to use this "old-fashioned" approach.

Comment: Also, for directing to your developer page (if you want to show the user your catalogue of apps) you can use:
NSString *simple = @"itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/YOUR_COMPANY_NAME";

Comment: Where do I find this id ?

Comment: Summer 2015?! Like the entire world lives in the same country. :(

Answer (score 38):

To have a direct link without redirection :

1. Use Apple Services Marketing Tools : https://tools.applemediaservices.com/ to get the real direct link
2. Replace the `https://` with `itms-apps://`
3. Open the link with `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])`

Be careful, those links only works on actual devices, not in simulator.

Source :

- Comments : credit to @rwcorbett for the new link
- Apple documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1629.html

Comment: +1 for itunes.apple.com/linkmaker,everyone test the link in device not in simulator, I was wasting time in testing simulator.

Comment: Thanks for info about Simulator, I'll add this to the answer

Comment: this is now `https://tools.applemediaservices.com/app-store/`

Answer (score 32):

This code generates the App Store link on iOS

```
NSString *appName = [NSString stringWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]   objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"]];
NSURL *appStoreURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.com/app/%@",[appName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]]];
```

Replace itms-apps with http on Mac:

```
NSURL *appStoreURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/itunes.com/app/%@",[appName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]]];
```

Open URL on iOS:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appStoreURL];
```

Mac:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:appStoreURL];
```

Comment: This works, but you also have to remove special characters like dashes from the app name.

Comment: Can we open and show all the apps uploaded by the developer in one page?

Comment: This was the only drop-in solution that worked for me with minimum redirects and maximum handling of app name whitespace.

Answer (score 30):

Simply change 'itunes' to 'phobos' in the app link.

http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=300136119&mt=8

Now it will open the App Store directly

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me perfectly using only APP ID:

```
 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@",YOUR_APP_ID];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

**The number of redirects is ZERO.**

Answer (score 14):

A number of answers suggest using 'itms' or 'itms-apps' but this practice is not specifically recommended by Apple. They only offer the following way to open the App Store:

**Listing 1**  *Launching the App Store from an iOS application*

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1629/_index.html last updated March, 2014 as of this answer.

For apps that support iOS 6 and above, Apple offers a in-app mechanism for presenting the App Store: `SKStoreProductViewController`

```
- (void)loadProductWithParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL result, NSError *error))block;

// Example:
SKStoreProductViewController* spvc = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
spvc.delegate = self;
[spvc loadProductWithParameters:@{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : @(364709193) } completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error){ 
    if (error)
        // Show sorry
    else
        // Present spvc
}];
```

Note that on iOS6, the completion block may not be called if there are errors. This appears to be a bug that was resolved in iOS 7.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to link to a developer's apps and the developer's name has punctuation or spaces (e.g. Development Company, LLC) form your URL like this:

```
itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/DevelopmentCompanyLLC
```

Otherwise it returns "This request cannot be processed" on iOS 4.3.3

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, try the following syntax: itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/ChuckSmith/id290402113 replacing my name with your company and my ID with your Artist ID which you can get from the iTunes link maker: http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/

Comment: You could also try to encode those "special" chars - i.e. replace "." with "%2E"

Comment: that is THE prefect answer!

Answer (score 13):

You can get a link to a specific item in the app store or iTunes through the link maker at:
http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/

Comment: This one help me, because the link in my itunes-connect didn't work, and in the generator it does. thank you

Answer (score 9):

This is working and directly linking in ios5

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://itunes.apple.com/app/baseball-stats-tracker-touch/id490256272?mt=8";  
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

Answer (score 9):

All the answers are outdated and don't work; use the below method.

All apps of a developer:
`itms-apps://apps.apple.com/developer/developer-name/developerId`

Single app:
`itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/appId`

Answer (score 8):

This is simple and short way to redirect/link other existing application on app store.

```
 NSString *customURL = @"http://itunes.apple.com/app/id951386316";

 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
 {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

For Xcode 9.1 and Swift 4:

1. Import StoreKit:

> ```
> import StoreKit
> ```

2.Conform the protocol

```
SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate
```

3.Implement the protocol

```
func openStoreProductWithiTunesItemIdentifier(identifier: String) {
    let storeViewController = SKStoreProductViewController()
    storeViewController.delegate = self

    let parameters = [ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : identifier]
    storeViewController.loadProduct(withParameters: parameters) { [weak self] (loaded, error) -> Void in

        if loaded {
            // Parent class of self is UIViewContorller
            self?.present(storeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }   
}
```

3.1

```
func productViewControllerDidFinish(_ viewController: SKStoreProductViewController) {
    viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

4. How to use:

> ```
> openStoreProductWithiTunesItemIdentifier(identifier: "here_put_your_App_id")
> ```

Note:

> **It is very important to enter the exact ID of your APP. Because this cause error (not show the error log, but nothing works fine because of this)**

Comment: I am doing the same thing, running on the device. No success

Answer (score 6):

I can confirm that if you create an app in iTunes connect you get your app id before you submit it.

Therefore..

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id123456789

NSURL *appStoreURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id123456789"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:appStoreURL])
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:appStoreURL];
```

Works a treat

Answer (score 5):

I think Apple has provided a new link for the app link:
https://apps.apple.com/app/id1445530088 or https://apps.apple.com/app/ {your_app_id}

Comment: For website links, this is the way to go. Can't believe this URL is so ridiculously hard to find.

Comment: this deep links into the App Store. the url with https://itunes.apple.com/app/appId redirects to https://apps.apple.com/app/appId . If you copy the URL from the App Store page it will give you a URL with the https://apps.apple.com domain. So to deeplink to apps on the App Store a URL like https://apps.apple.com/app/appId seems most up to date.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a link could become a complex issue when supporting multiple OS and multiple platform. For example the WebObjects isn't supported on iOS 7 (some of them), some links you create would open another country store then the user's etc.

There is an open source library called [iLink](https://github.com/sidan5/iLink) that could help you.

There advantages of this library is that **the links would be found and created at run time** (the library would check the app ID and the OS it is running on and would figure out what link should be created). The best point in this is that you don't need to configure almost anything before using it so that is error free and would work always. That's great also if you have few targets on same project so you don't have to remember which app ID or link to use. This library also would prompt the user to upgrade the app if there is a new version on the store (this is built in and you turn this off by a simple flag) directly pointing to the upgrade page for the app if user agrees.

Copy the 2 library files to your project (iLink.h & iLink.m).

On your appDelegate.m:

```
#import "iLink.h"

+ (void)initialize
{
    //configure iLink
    [iLink sharedInstance].globalPromptForUpdate = YES; // If you want iLink to prompt user to update when the app is old.
}
```

and on the place you want to open the rating page for example just use:

```
[[iLink sharedInstance] iLinkOpenAppPageInAppStoreWithAppleID: YOUR_PAID_APP_APPLE_ID]; // You should find YOUR_PAID_APP_APPLE_ID from iTunes Connect
```

Don't forget to import iLink.h on the same file.

There is a very good doc for the whole library there and an example projects for iPhone and for Mac.

Answer (score 4):

## At least iOS 9 and above

- Open directly in the App Store

#### An app

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/[appName]/[appID]
```

#### List of developer's apps

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/developer/[developerName]/[developerID]
```

Comment: `appName` is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Apple's latest document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1629/_index.html) 
You need to use

```
appStoreLink = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8"
```

or

```
SKStoreProductViewController
```

Comment: Can you update your link please? This seems quite interesting if that won't work.

Comment: The linked document doesn't mention `itms:` or `itms-apps:`. Links using that scheme work fine on my devices running iOS 12.

Answer (score 4):

Despite there being loads of answers here, none of the suggestions for linking to the developers apps seem to work anymore.

When I last visited I was able to get it working using the format:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/developer/developer-name/id123456789
```

This no longer works, but removing the developer name does:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/developer/id123456789
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the app store id you are best off using it. Especially if you in the future might change the name of the application.

```
http://itunes.apple.com/app/id378458261
```

If you don't have tha app store id you can create an url based on this documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html

```
+ (NSURL *)appStoreURL
{
    static NSURL *appStoreURL;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        appStoreURL = [self appStoreURLFromBundleName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"]];
    });
    return appStoreURL;
}

+ (NSURL *)appStoreURLFromBundleName:(NSString *)bundleName
{
    NSURL *appStoreURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.com/app/%@", [self sanitizeAppStoreResourceSpecifier:bundleName]]];
    return appStoreURL;
}

+ (NSString *)sanitizeAppStoreResourceSpecifier:(NSString *)resourceSpecifier
{
    /*
     https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html
     To create an App Store Short Link, apply the following rules to your company or app name:

     Remove all whitespace
     Convert all characters to lower-case
     Remove all copyright (©), trademark (™) and registered mark (®) symbols
     Replace ampersands ("&") with "and"
     Remove most punctuation (See Listing 2 for the set)
     Replace accented and other "decorated" characters (ü, å, etc.) with their elemental character (u, a, etc.)
     Leave all other characters as-is.
     */
    resourceSpecifier = [resourceSpecifier stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"and"];
    resourceSpecifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[resourceSpecifier dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    resourceSpecifier = [resourceSpecifier stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[!¡\"#$%'()*+,-./:;<=>¿?@\\[\\]\\^_`{|}~\\s\\t\\n]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, resourceSpecifier.length)];
    resourceSpecifier = [resourceSpecifier lowercaseString];
    return resourceSpecifier;
}
```

Passes this test

```
- (void)testAppStoreURLFromBundleName
{
    STAssertEqualObjects([AGApplicationHelper appStoreURLFromBundleName:@"Nuclear™"].absoluteString, @"itms-apps://itunes.com/app/nuclear", nil);
    STAssertEqualObjects([AGApplicationHelper appStoreURLFromBundleName:@"Magazine+"].absoluteString, @"itms-apps://itunes.com/app/magazine", nil);
    STAssertEqualObjects([AGApplicationHelper appStoreURLFromBundleName:@"Karl & CO"].absoluteString, @"itms-apps://itunes.com/app/karlandco", nil);
    STAssertEqualObjects([AGApplicationHelper appStoreURLFromBundleName:@"[Fluppy fuck]"].absoluteString, @"itms-apps://itunes.com/app/fluppyfuck", nil);
    STAssertEqualObjects([AGApplicationHelper appStoreURLFromBundleName:@"Pollos Hérmanos"].absoluteString, @"itms-apps://itunes.com/app/polloshermanos", nil);
    STAssertEqualObjects([AGApplicationHelper appStoreURLFromBundleName:@"Niños and niñas"].absoluteString, @"itms-apps://itunes.com/app/ninosandninas", nil);
    STAssertEqualObjects([AGApplicationHelper appStoreURLFromBundleName:@"Trond, MobizMag"].absoluteString, @"itms-apps://itunes.com/app/trondmobizmag", nil);
    STAssertEqualObjects([AGApplicationHelper appStoreURLFromBundleName:@"!__SPECIAL-PLIZES__!"].absoluteString, @"itms-apps://itunes.com/app/specialplizes", nil);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Most of the solutions here are outdated & deprecated

#### For those looking for the updated working solution

```
// let appStoreLink = "https://apps.apple.com/app/{app-name}/{app-id}"

guard let url = URL(string: Constants.App.appStoreLink) else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

Comment: This seems to work for me in 2023. It seems all the previous methods that did not also include the app-id no longer work.

Using the itms-apps://apps.apple.com/app/{app-name}/{app-id} suffix on a Mac also works, and might be one less load in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

it will open the App Store directly

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/ebl- 
skybanking/id1171655193?mt=8";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id="your app ID here" return json.From this, find key "**trackViewUrl**" and value is the desired url. use this url(just replace `https://` with `itms-apps://`).This works just fine.

For example if your app ID is xyz then go to this link
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=xyz

Then find the url for key "**trackViewUrl**".This is the url for your app in app store and to use this url in xcode try this

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/Your app name/id Your app ID?mt=8&uo=4";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### in SwiftUI - IOS 15.0

```
//
//  Test.swift
//  PharmaCodex
//

import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button(action: {
                guard let writeReviewURL = URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/app/id1629135515?action=write-review") else {
                    fatalError("Expected a valid URL")
                }
                UIApplication.shared.open(writeReviewURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                
            }) {
                Text("Rate/Review")
            }
            
            
        }
    }
}

struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me (in 2023) `itms-apps://` doesn't work but `itms-appss://` does!

```js
itms-appss://apps.apple.com/app/idYOUR_ID_HERE
```

I suspect Apple added the extra `s` because they don't want us using it any more but there are some edge cases where it's still extremely helpful.

For 99% of cases you'll want to use the regular link:

```
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wavelength/idYOUR_ID_HERE
```