# How to search the App Store programmatically and return App information

Tags: ios, ios4, app-store

I would like to search the Apple App Store from within my app, and return App information such as Icon, Description, Name, etc.
I found some examples using URL's. But from what I understand, they cause your app to pause as it opens either the App Store or the browser. If I am mistaken, please may you provide me with an example on how to accomplish this (seemingly) simple task?

Regards,

Shane

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically run a search on the App Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632009/programmatically-run-a-search-on-the-app-store)

Comment: @Kristopher I don't think thats what he's trying to accomplish, I think he wants to search the app store without opening the app store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an API available to do what you are describing directly in the iOS device. However, you could hack something together using the search API available from apple. Check it out at [here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html). You could do this behind the scenes rather then using the browser. It's not a simple task, but it is doable. Besk of luck.

Comment: Thanks Eytan. I thought as much. Was hoping there was an easier way.

Comment: You can also download a library that does it for you at this link : https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion