# open app store for specific with in ipad/iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store

how to open app store and search specific application in app store or a specific publishers application in our ipad/iphone application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to link to the page of a single author/company page on the App Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060699/how-to-link-to-the-page-of-a-single-author-company-page-on-the-app-store)

Comment: NSString *str = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/CompanyName";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:str]]; It's Working for me but i want to open app store within my application its takes me itunes store and the control is out from my application can any one suggest me other solution how can i open app store with in my application and control always remains in my hand???

Answer (score 0):

Are you not aware that there is a search bar in iTunes through which you can search any application by its name or by the name of the company.

Comment: i am aware with search bar but i want to open app store on clicking of one button let's say More App with particular publisher???

Answer (score 0):

In general, go to the page you're interested in within iTunes. Then if it's an app, right click the big app icon in the top left and select 'Copy Link'. If it's a company, right click their name on the 'more by ...' page. If it's some other page, look for the appropriate thing to click.

You'll get a direct link URL on the clipboard. For example, [this](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/artist/loud-crow-interactive-inc/id397864716) is the link for Loud Crow Interactive (who I'm not affiliated with but who have an app on the front page right now, causing them to be selected by me at random).