# how to open app store with in our ipad or iphone application?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store

Hi i want to open app store with in our application with the specific publisher search or specific application types..on clicking of button..let's say More App's...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to link to the page of a single author/company page on the App Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060699/how-to-link-to-the-page-of-a-single-author-company-page-on-the-app-store)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. You can get the appropriate URL to your app here:

   **http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker**

   If you enter the name of your company the linkmaker will provide an "artist link" that shows all of your apps.
2. If you use the **itms-apps://** prefix the user is sent directly to the
   App Store App with the specified app showing rather than the ugly
   first-Safari-then-the-App-Store-App shuffle that you get without that
   UTI. A la:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:  
                                            @"itms-apps://yourAppLinkHere"]];
```

Answer (score 4):

To generate a link that is universal and not specific to an App Store Country do the following

Use

```
itms-apps://**ax.itunes**.apple.com/app/yourAppLinker
```

where yourAppLinker is the part of the link generated in (http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker), as in Matthew Frederick's post, which contains your application name and id

it worked for me

cheers

Answer (score 4):

For IOS7 and later for example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id547101139"]];
```