# Open ( App Store ) programmatically

Tags: app-store

I want open AppStore from Inside my app programmatically

( without close my app )

How can I do this in iOS 8 ,, iOS 9

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to open app store with in our ipad or iphone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437779/how-to-open-app-store-with-in-our-ipad-or-iphone-application)

Answer (score 0):

There is the `SKStoreProductView` where you can open a specific product page from the App Store without the user actually leaving your app.

Find the official docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/