# How do I link to another app in the App Store in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I used [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store), but it appears to not work anymore in 3.0. In the simulator at least, my app opens Safari, and then there is a visible redirect, but then I get a message that there has been too many redirects. Any fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this on the device?  There is no App Store application on the Simulator, so any attempts to redirect to it will fail.

Within my application, the itunes.apple.com links for the App Store work just fine under 3.0 on the actual devices.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this right now, but have you tried changing the 'http:' protocol in the link to 'itms:' instead?