# linking to an app on the Itunes store

Tags: iphone, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

A few web searches yield all sorts of contradictory advice on linking from an iPhone app to an app on the store.  Here are some links that come up, together with comments from testing:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/anagramania/id360016055?mt=8 -- works great.  But is it US only?

http://itunes.com/apps/anagramania -- works after a bunch of redirects, which are likely to annoy the customer.

http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=360016055&mt=8 -- works great.  But Apple appears to be trying to remove "phobos" links from its documentation.

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=360016055&mt=8 -- works great, but Apple's documentation mentions problems with similar links.  Apple doc here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1633.html#STANDARD_APPSTORE_LINKS

Can anyone bring order out of this chaos?

Comment: Even though this question provides more detail, it appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186410/how-do-i-link-to-another-app-in-the-app-store-in-an-iphone-app, and possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513945/how-can-i-give-app-store-link-in-my-apps-before-approving-another-apps

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the first link.  If you're concerned about the country, take it out.  If you remove `/us` from that link, it still works:
http://itunes.apple.com/app/anagramania/id360016055?mt=8

**Better Yet,**
Apply to be an Apple Affiliate and use that link instead.  Then you'll get 5% on any purchases made using that link:
http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/