# Sharing application link via the same application, iphone

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

> **Possible duplicate:**
>
> - [How can i give app store link in my apps before approving another apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513945/how-can-i-give-app-store-link-in-my-apps-before-approving-another-apps)
> - [linking to an app on the Itunes store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437135/linking-to-an-app-on-the-itunes-store-closed)
> - [How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

Hi all,
I'm a littile bit confused. I need to provide the download link of my application (the iTunes link) inside my application. ie when the user would like to invite others via mail or some other means, have to provide the application link too with that.Is there any way to provide that before submitting the application to apple. Or i need to use the link as an update after getting my application approved by apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to provide an iTunes URL, you should know the unique ID for your app and AFAIK, there's no way to get this ID before getting your app in the store first.

You can try and construct a search URL, but it doesn't always give the desired result. For example, I currently have only one app in the store, but there's another developer who uses the same developer name as me, so a search URL for my app produces two results. If this is your first app, and searching for your developer name produces no results, it *could* be safe for you to go with a search URL.

Even if you use a search URL, you will want to replace it with a proper iTunes URL in the first update.

Read this article by Bjango for more information on iTunes URLs and quirks of using search URLs: [Dissecting iTunes links](http://bjango.com/articles/ituneslinks/)