# Downloading multiple apps from the app store

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, app-store

I'm new to iOS, and I'm looking for a creative solution to a simple problem.

Now, if I want to send a user to the app store in order to purchase one app, I know how to do so (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store/).

But, inside my app, I'd like to create a straightforward way to link to a *collection* of apps (not from the same seller). Or, better yet, I'd like to create a way for a user to download multiple apps with the fewest clicks possible.

I've contemplated some solutions, but I'm not sure which are feasible. I'm also not sure if I'm missing something obvious. The two options I've thought of thus far are (drum roll):

1. **Create an app collection**, and link to it. I know that Apple can create collections in this way (http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewGrouping?id=25180&mt=8) but I'm not sure if a poor bloke like myself can do the same.
2. **Create a bunch of links to individual apps**. I don't like this solution, as the user has to toggle multiple times between my app and the app store.

Any creative or technical input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If these apps are by the same seller, just link to the seller (or a search for the seller name).

Comment: Yeah. I knew that! But these apps are not from the same seller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but try using a webview, and load the itunes web link for each app in a separate frame.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, owook. This is the kind of creative thinking that I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Theres no built in way to automatically download another app from within your app, except through iads, but thats not what you talking about.  The only thing you can do is put multiple links.  You would be able to search for all the apps by one account, except you said it’ll be from multiple accounts.

Sorry, but theres presently no built in way to do what your saying.