# Opening iTunes link on iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, itunes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

I want to link all my apps on my main app if that makes sense
So i have a button, when the user touches it

they will be directed to this link:

> http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/idubstep/id430260356?mt=8

However

```
 -(IBAction)goReviewTwo:(id)sender
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/gb/artist/lifevision-studios/id415139916"]];
}
```

This always say `Request cannot be complete`. So is there a special link i need to use for it?

Answer (score 2):

There are several threads answering this question.  Here is one: [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

Note the comment that suggests using itms:// instead of http://