# Opening up App Store to Rate from within my App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store

I was wondering if it is possible to take my user directly to the review section of my app on the app store from within my app?

I don't want this to open in Safari, I want it to directly open the App Store app on the device and take them to the review page.

I have tried the following;

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=437688779&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software"]];
```

However, clicking that seems to open up the iTunes app and not app store and then just gives an error saying "Cannot Connect to the store.  A secure connection could not be established".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As seen in [this blog:](http://www.memention.com/blog/2009/09/03/Open-Reviews.html)

```
- (IBAction)gotoReviews:(id)sender
{
    NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa";
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?", str]; 
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@type=Purple+Software&id=", str];

    // Here is the app id from itunesconnect
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@yourAppIDHere", str]; 

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
}
```

Comment: Don't use -[NSString stringWithFormat:] when you're just appending string. -[NSString stringByAppendingString:] will do just the same, but much faster and efficiently (no buffers, etc.).

Comment: You can skip the "type=..." part so that the url reads ".../viewContentsUserReviews?id=...". This works for iOS 7.1.2 as well as 8.0.2 (tested on real devices).

Answer (score 24):

There seems to be an issue worth mentioning in iOS 7.0 as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905686/itunes-review-url-and-ios-7-ask-user-to-rate-our-app-appstore-show-a-blank-pag). You can see how Appirator dealt with the problem in their source [here](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/blob/master/Appirater.m).

Basically, you need to handle 7.0 users differently, as so: (the first line is the same as the accepted solution, the appended strings are just on the same line.)

```
NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=yourAppIDHere";
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
    str = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idyourAppIDHere";
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```

---

**Update 19 August 2015**

The URLs above don't work for iOS 8.0. Updated code catering for all iOS versions would be:

```
NSString *str;
float ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (ver >= 7.0 && ver < 7.1) {
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@",appID];
} else if (ver >= 8.0) {
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=%@&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software",appID];
} else {
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=%@",appID];
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```

Source: [Appirator](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/blob/master/Appirater.m)

---

**Update 14 November 2017**

From iOS 10.3, we can request a review using the [SKStoreReviewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller), which actually opens a neat little popover in your app rather than navigating away from your app:

```
if (@available(iOS 10.3, *)) {
  [SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You want an `itms://` link, and [here's](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/) a handy place to generate one. Make sure you change the protocol from `http(s):` to `itms:` (or `itms-apps:` which seems to be the new way).

Comment: Hi, I have tried that also.  Sorry, should have mentioned.  Also does not work

Comment: Make sure you change the protocol from `http(s):` to `itms:`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the class [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate), did work well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:- `@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=%@";`

Answer (score 0):

use this its also help you.

```
  NSString *fdAppUrl=@"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id1137341185?mt=8";

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fdAppUrl]];
```

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store](http://check%20here%20too.)