# iphone - adding option for gifting the app

Tags: iphone

In my iphone app, i'd like to add the option to "Gift" the app.
Basically I like to add a button which pops up the username to whom i want to gift.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know this functionality is part of the App Store and there is no API to provide that functionality in-app.

Cheers
Shai

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is make the "gift" button open up the app store pointing to the app's page (which is still useful, IMO).

Once you have the web URL for your app, tell your UIApplication to open it and the user will land in the App Store app:

[How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

Make sure you use the itms-apps:// hint below the accepted answer or you'll wind up with a double redirect which is annoying.