# Link to look-like App on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

I followed this really great instructions: http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen
to create a look-like App for iPhone, by adding a link to the home-screen and adding a nice icon, startscreen, and so on...

Now I have a question:

If I send the user some E-Mail (or Textmessage), in which the user can find some Link (Url) and he clicks the link: how can I force the device to open the "App" instead of the browser?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store

Comment: Well, it's actually no real app; it's just a favorite on the home screen. I want, if the user has the favorite on it's home screen, open the link in the look-like app and not in the browser. Know what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a web-app there is no way to do this, only a native app can be started via an app url sheme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) to pack you website in a app. Then you can make a link to it.