# Develop a trial version of the paid version of an iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have an iPhone app that is available on app store, free of cost. Now I want to make the same app to be paid. No problem til then. But the challenge before me is to release the trial version of the same app with few of features disabled or not shown at all. What I want is to put a button on the trial app that will took the user to app store for the paid version.

How to do this?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (IBAction) openPremierVersionAppStore {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shaifgupta/app_id"]];
}
```