# Can i get a link to my app before i publish it in the Apple Appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store

Can I get a link to my app (to open it directly from the device) before I publish it in the Appstore? I want to do in my App click button "Rate this app".

It's simple in Google Play (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.mycompany.myapp) or Amazon AppStore, but how to do it for the Apple AppStore?

Comment: Well, but i see it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link to apps on the app store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you can log in to

> itunesconnect.apple.com

, select your app, there is a link `View in App Store`
This button will give you the appstore link even if the app is still not in there