# How to get iOS App icon link from iTunes?

Tags: ios, itunes

Is there any way to get iOS app icon link from iTunes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the app's icon's link? Open the app's link in web browser not in itunes. Right click the app's icon. Choose inspect element, then you can see the link to that image. First of all the app must already in AppStore.
[image]

If you want to get the link to your app before you submit it to AppStore. You can try [this](http://itunesconnect.apple.com).

Select your app, there is a link View in App Store, this button will give you the appstore link even if the app is still not in there

Refer to this SO question:[Can i get a link to my app before i publish it in the Apple Appstore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927996/can-i-get-a-link-to-my-app-before-i-publish-it-in-the-apple-appstore)

Comment: thanks for reply.But i don't need ios app link but iOS app ICON IMAGE link.