# business card with qr code linked to app store to download iPhone app

Tags: iphone, itunes, qr-code

i want to print a business card with a qr code that links directly to the app store on the iPhone for download

that is easy to do

issue is..when we upload a new version of the app....will that qr code still work? because am printing business cards that's why am worried.

let me know
xxxx

Answer (score 2):

Print your QR code to a static link that you can then control where it redirects to.

QR Code -> [www.Your-Webpage.com/redirecttoapp.html] -> [Your webpage redirects to app store]

You can then change it at a later date to point to anything you want without having to reprint your cards should the need arise.

Edit:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store) is the URL Schema for the Apple AppStore.
Just A thought but you could also build in some Browser Detection into your Redirect page.
E.G: If iphone redirect to apple AppStore, If Android Redirect to Market Place.
If you don't have a android app you could redirect to your business webpage.

Comment: thanks for replying..but the link is a link to the app store on the iPhone..not a web address.so when you scan it with your phone you go to the app store on the iPhone itself. let me know

Comment: Edited my answer to include more information. In your question you say "I want to print a business card", So I assume you haven't printed them yet and can just get a new QR Code.