# iOS - Lauch other apps with search keywords

Tags: ios, app-store, youtube-api

It is possible to launch another app (such as youtube, AppStore,Map, etc) from my iOS app & give it keyword for searching?

For example, I would like provide to user ability search cartoon video from my app & show the results in Youtube app.

Please share your though/

Thanks,
Huy

Comment: Find answers for my question. To launch appstore with search term using itms-apps://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&term=%@. Search term with Map app using http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@. But there is no way to do the same with Youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to communicate with other apps is through URLs.  Have a look at [communicating with other apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18).  To answer your question, just create a URL that contains the search terms.

Since tagged app-store in your question, I'm sure you find this useful: [How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store).

> A tip is to use itms:// instead of http://, then it'll open in the app
>   store directl

Comment: Thanks, It looks like it depends on URLs provided by apps(Youtube,Map,AppStore)