# How to List all exisiting iOS apps in one iOS app and option to download from there

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I am trying to make an iOS app that show all catalog-existing my iOS apps (of appstore) and user can  download those apps on device from there, (similar to app store).

Please suggest how this is possible

```
UItableView *tblAppList = [[UItableview alloc]init];
```

Comment: If I understand what you want to do, I think this thread has some hints for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store

Comment: Thx for ur comment. but I want to show all my live apps already on app store in one app and user can download from there.

Comment: Right, so if you create links the way that thread describes (with 'itms'), you can use `openURL:` to trigger a connection when someone selects one of them.

Comment: Do you actually have multiple apps in the app store?

Comment: Yes, My client have multiple similar apps related to students learning  stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the list of app's to be dynamically pulled from the app store? If you did, then you would have to write some XML parser and place a query searching by developer, with your developer name. You would then need to extract the useful parts of the data, such as the app title, link to the app store, and icon image. You would then pass the into the table view.

For more on how to query the iTunes store look here;

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Comment: could you plz let me clear what parameter name I have to pass for getting all my apps listing

i mean what url would be:  http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=909253

parameter: lookup/id or developerID or anything else ?

Comment: For developer you could probably do; http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=developerName&entity=software

Comment: good... One more question comes in my mind regarding downloading the ... After this search result display on table listing.. is there would be option to download that app inside the app ? or it will quit the app and iTunes/Appstore app will be opened to download that app (choosen by user) please.. make this clear... Actually I want to give ability to users to download any app from listing  without going to itunes store / appstore app .. is this possible

Comment: No, it will have to go through the iTunes store.