# How to work out the itms-apps link for an app, pre submission?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Before submitting the app that I'm working on, I want application to include a link to the app in the App Store (it will be within an email, generated by the app).

I've read a bunch of posts, including this one:
[How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

So I know the format of the link that I'm going to use. It will be:

itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/appname

What I want to double check - is the appname itself.
Specifically, the difference between the bundle name and the bundle display name.

For example, if I have set the bundle display name to be:
**awesome'app**

But the bundle name is simply:
**awesomeapp**

In Xcode, Targets -> Build Settings -> Packaging, Product Name = awesomeapp
This is what gets used for the Bundle name, as it is set to be: ${PRODUCT_NAME}

I'm making an assumption that it's better to not have an apostrophe in the product name, so I'm manually setting the Bundle display name to be: awesome'app

Question 1: as I have it now, will the 'appname' in the itms-apps link be "awesomeapp"?

Question 2: if it's actually just fine to use awesome'app throughout the Xcode project (therefore not having to manually set the Bundle display name), what would the itms-apps link be? Would it still be:

itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/awesomeapp

Thanks,
Gavin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you create your app in iTunes Connect, you will get a link that will point to your app once it's live on the AppStore. Use that link.

[image: iTunes Connect app details]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the pointer. I only just created the app in iTunesConnect today, so I wanted to wait until I'd done that before commenting on your answer.

Even before the app is available in the store, that link does give you the url for connecting to the store. In my case - I took the part of the url that had the app name - to be sure that I'd used the correct link in this form:


itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/appname


Cheers,
Gavin