# Can Apple App Store URL change after resubmitting iOS app?

Tags: ios, url, app-store, submit

I wouldn't expect it to, but I need to be 100% sure before we get our leaflets printed... could the URL of our app (already in the the app store) change if we submit a new version in the future?

The URL of our app is:
https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/OUR-APP-NAME/idOUR-APP-ID?mt=8

Comment: check if this answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you are updating your app, that is, submitting a new version, the URL won't change.  You will have your app name and app ID stay the same thus the URL doesn't change.  I have a link in my webpage that links to my app in the app store and has stayed working for many years and many versions of my app.

Comment: Great, thanks. Presumably, the URL would only change if you changed the name of the app?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use some redirection? Print your leaflet so it points to your own website, www.mycompany.com/myGreatApp.html, and on that page have the link to the Apple Store.

You get 2 big benefits this way. First, your URL is shorter and easier to type, and second, you don't have to ever worry about Apple changing the URL. As GabCas points out they, won't, but your own web page is much better anyhow in a printed medium.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of that, but the URL is going to be embedded in a QR code anyway. Plus, I'm not sure my client will want to set up redirects anyway so I just need to keep it simple for them.

Comment: ahhh, that makes sense then. Go with GabCas then (and edit the question).

Comment: To be fair, I don't think it does. And even if I used a redirect, I'd still need to know the answer to my original question in order to know whether we may need need to update the redirect URL in the future.