# Want to display third party app in my app

Tags: iphone, ios

My client asked me to display his previous app in his app, so that a user can also download this app.

That's fine but he also asked if he can advertise a third party app in this app,  and I can't find any related answer in Google so I think to ask expert. Please need help on this topic.

Comment: What do you mean by "advertise" ? If it is just linking to another app so the user can download it, you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store) question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the web view and load the Appstore link of the respective app in the web view. From where you can download the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can advertise in your own app.  There are all sorts of third party advertisers you can use.  There's no reason you can't do your own advertisement.