# Interface to the AppStore?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, passbook

I have a requirement that a client wants to be able to allow users to download apps from within an app (which I will call the main app), based on a user's score (when a user achieves a certain score, they can have an app). We would like to do this without linking to the app store directly, so that users of the main app can be granted access to another app.

So, is there a way to interface to the app store while hiding the official app store from the user? I have seen similar functionality in Passbook, but not exactly what we are looking for. Any ideas? Thanks! Viv

Comment: Short answer : nope ! ;) I believe In App Purchases is your best option.

Comment: You could deliver them a passbook pass containing the link to your App on the back.  Since your goal appears to be to acknowledge achievement, a pass could be an appropriate medium to recognise and reward.  It also provides you another channel to engage with the user.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate

[How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

If your app is in Apple appstore, you can use itms:// service to install apps directly. Check the above link that tells awesome stuff about the apple app store itms services.