# How to make a url to Apple app store or Google play to actually open the app store?

Tags: android, html, ios, mobile

I have a website which has links that sends people to the app store and google play to download my app.

But regular links just go to the website. How can I change it so that if people are on mobile devices, the link opens the app store or google play for them?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: For android, you should use url = "market://details?id=..." which will direct you to google play or any other market.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Android apps, you can just link to the Google play store directly. The Android OS will prompt the user if they want to open the link in their browser or open the link in the Google Play store app as soon as they click on it. Any http://play.google.com?id=* link will prompt the user in this way on an Android device.

If you've got an Android phone, just give it a try [with this link to the Facebook app for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana)

For iPhone, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2337601/815679) that is very complete for what you want to do.

Comment: I tried linking to the google play store. But it took me  to the url of the app in the store. But didn't open the actual google play. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I do know what you mean, I think. So it opened the browser directly? In my experience, that isn't what happens. For all of my Android devices, any Play Store link will prompt so that the user can select the Play Store app if they choose to. What OS/Device are you using?

Comment: Then you need to "Clear defaults" for the app that is launching (in Android). This means you have selected "Always Use" at some point when you visited a Play Store link. There is some info here (related to a different app) http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/how-to-change-a-default-application-in-ice-cream-sandwich

Comment: I have a bit of an older Android phone (2 years) so maybe that is why it only went to google play store on the web.

Comment: I'm actually using an older Android phone as well as my regular every day phone (~2 years as well, LG Optimus V), and I am seeing the behavior that Google Play opens. I would definitely look into the link that @Tigger posted, it's possible that your phone is set to purposely open the Play Store links in the browser and you could potentially reset it.

Answer (score 6):

I used [onelink.to](http://onelink.to) and it's working great so far, it generates a QRcode as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use http://toSto.re to redirect people to the right app store or your website depending on the user agent the users have set.

URLs like toSto.re/dawawas can be configured easily there.

Comment: One of the biggest disadvantages is that you can't edit the created url.

Comment: is ToStore still operational?  The site sign up process seems operational, but I never received an email with my customized link.

Comment: 2023 Update. I can confirm ToStore does not send the email confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [tny.ws](https://tny.ws) to create one link and smart QR code for my apps on PlayStore and AppStore. There is no limit on the number of QR we can create. I think its good to use.