# How do you set a background image for your app listing in the Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

Take Pixelmator for example: http://appstore.com/mac/pixelmator

How do they have a background image set?

Comment: In my view this question is valid, should fall into the "software tools commonly used by programmers". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store for other app store question

Comment: I agree; it's useful information for app development which isn't covered anywhere in the App Store documentation (even to explain that it's not available by default).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to be specially selected by Apple in order to do this; it's not something all developers can do unfortunately.

Comment: I believe it's associated with your app having been featured on the App Store by Apple. For instance, Pixelmator currently shows up in the header of the front page.