# tvOS: where do we setup app theme background image shown in the tvOS app store

Tags: tvos

When we browse apps in the tvOS app store and select one app, the app store will show a themed image as the background for the selected app, I play around in Xcode tvOS project but not find where I can setup such a background for my tvOS app.

I only setup a small layered icon, large layered icon, top shelf image and launch image, none of them can be that theme background.

Does anyone know how I can setup it?

Thanks.

Comment: I am also looking where to set this image. When just setting the sm & lrg layered icon in Xcode, the App Store will display the App Icon on the right and an expanded and blurred version as the background. I see a lot of apps that have a special image for the background (not blurred or expanded) and the App Icon is removed. Also, for apps' with this special background, they have an image as their App Name instead of text. Can anybody provide any information as to how I can incorporate this with my app?

Comment: Pretty sure the image and theme color is taken from your Top Shelf Image and Icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doesn't provide informations about image sizes and guidelines for this background image, so probably you need to get featured on the tvOS App Store like already happens in iOS and Mac App Stores. 
Usually if the app has a lot of downloads Apple can contact you for requesting more marketing materials.

Reference: [How do you set a background image for your app listing in the Mac App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525408/how-do-you-set-a-background-image-for-your-app-listing-in-the-mac-app-store)