# How can I reference an app that's not on the app store yet?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a free and pro version of my application. Inside of my app I have an area that talks about the pro version and I would like to have a button that links to it. Is it possible to do that before the app is on the app store? I just want that button to link directly to the pro version on the store.

I know it sound's like an obvious answer, no, but I don't know if there is some special reference link that you can get prior to submitting an app on the store.

Comment: @BrianNickel I actually looked at that post and it explains how to get the app id, but how do I turn that id into a link to the app store?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to iTunes Connect => Manage your apps => select your app => under links: View in App Store . This link will be your direct link to your app.