# Problems open AppStore programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, nsworkspace

I'm having problems opening the app store (to suggest an app update).

This is what i'm doing:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"macappstore://itunes.apple.com/app/id[my_id]?mt=12"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

canOpenURL is returning false, also i tried without the conditional but it doesn't work.

In addition i tried to use NSWorkspace instead the openURL method in UIApplication but i'm having compilation errors, surely this are dependencies issues but i couldn't find Cocoa.framework and neither AppKit.framework to add one of them to the binaryLibraries of my project.

Comment: Are you trying this on the iPhone?  It won't work in the simulator.  Also, I don't think you need the "macappstore" prefix. "https" will do.

Comment: Oh! With https works. But, this open the safari browser before show the appStore app. I'm trying this on the device, yes.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you should be using the prefix `itms-apps://` instead of `macappstore://`. This will link you directly to the App Store app, instead of through a Safari redirect (as `http://` or `https://` will do).

Lots more on this topic covered here:
[How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)