# iOS URI link to an app in App Store (itms-apps)

Tags: ios, iphone

I can only find secondary sources of information about itms-apps scheme from Stackoverflow and HandleOpenUrl.

Is there any official documentation saying how to use itms-apps or who maintains it?

Comment: There is no official documentation about the `itms-apps` URL scheme. My [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21213833/368085) below gives you the best unofficial information available.

Comment: Here is the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [source](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate/blob/master/iRate/iRate.m) from Nick Lockwood's [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate) project:

iOS6 (and earlier):

`itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=`

iOS7:

`itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id`

You have to just append the app ID to the strings above to complete the URL.

AFAIK there is no official source of this information, it has probably been reverse engineered.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this and it works on iOS9:

`itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idID_OF_YOUR_APP` and it will open the app directly in the store.

Answer (score 0):

This link has the answer from apple Technical Q&A. [Creating easy-to-read short links to the App Store for your apps and company](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html) and [Launching the App Store from an iPhone application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1629/_index.html)

The second link comes from the page of the first link. I think it completes your request.

In a nutshell,

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id{your app id}?mt=8";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

Comment: sorry but this does not answer the question. no where in the document does it mention the scheme itms-apps

Comment: Please read through the documents, they are all linked together.

Comment: Also itms-apps seems not working with IOS7 anymore. Please check carefully.

Comment: Nowhere in the documentation you linked to (and nowhere I can find in any Apple Docs) mentions the `itms-apps` URL scheme, so you haven't answer the question. Also, `itms-apps` **does** work with iOS7, all though the URL format has changed. All this information is in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21213833/368085) to this question.

Comment: To tell you the truth, my application used iRate in the last release and it stopped working somehow now, that is why I suspected it is because of itms-apps. I tried to give official answer to avoid second hand source problem. It does not have to be itms-apps.

Comment: @Ethan I'm using iRate in one of my apps which is iOS7 only and it's working fine. It is odd that the itms-apps scheme is not officially documented.

Answer (score 0):

**handleOpenURL has been deprecated**. Use the application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: method instead. Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Then this following link tells about how to launch the App Store from an iPhone application:
[Launching the App Store from an iPhone application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1629/_index.html)