# Safari alert when try to redirect url to itunes running on localhost

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, mobile-safari

I am running a website using `node.js` which is currently running on my `localhost:{port_no}`. If we run our website on ipad/mobile device, then we need to redirect it to the App Store for downloading the App(available for device).

`window.location = 'https://itunes.apple.com/app/{app_id}';`

But, when i tried it in ipad simulator, then it show an message/alert `Safari cannot open this page, because the address is invalid.`

I tried it using both, `http` and `https`, but it doesn't work.

**NOTE:**
The same url is working on website(in localhost).

Thanks.

Comment: What do you pass in for {app_id}??

Comment: {app_id} is the id of the app. Its a valid url, it works fine on web browser.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store

Comment: @Benmj: Its doesn't work. I am running a web application on localhost. I think, this may be the issue. Any comment on that.

Comment: As per the link provided by Benmj, the above code does not seem to be working on iOS Simulator. You will need to make sure it works on the real device by running on it. Read the answers in the above link. Good one @Benmj but this isn't a duplicate question IMO..

Comment: Tested it on ipad device, instead of simulator and it works. Thanx everyone.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue. Some links work (user pressed) some do not (redirects via server 301/302 or some JS calls). I have found that if you delete the app it works! Looks like an odd Apple bug as it should take me to the app page with the open button (rather that purchase / install / etc).

In iOS 6 and 7 (we have no devices with older iOS and don't support them any more so I can vouch for them).

This is in simulator and real devices.