# How to add app store app link to in-app, not open "app store.app"?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

[image]
How to add app store app link to in-app, not open "app store.app".
Just open in my app window, not open in new app window.

So users can download, rate easier. 
Like this one in picture, it even changes the color of sub-window app store's color!

Comment: Would really like to know how this works. @Close Votes: Perfectly valid question, a little awkwardly asked, but rather interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Got me curious. The second answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store) has the solution: `SKStoreProductViewController` 
Have a look at that answer for an example, otherwise the Apple documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/SKStoreProductViewController.html).