# In need of a link to open an iOS app if installed or else go to the iTunes store

Tags: android, ios, facebook, hyperlink

My app (iOS and Android) wants to post in behalf of the user to Facebook, but I don't find an api in `FBWebDialog` class (FB iOS SDK) to set the message to post. So my first question is: is there any api in FB iOS/Android SDK to edit the post message (feed dialog)?

With this failure I hope to do this by posting a FB message with a links. So here is what my title suggests. Is it possible to have a link (URL) which, when clicked by the user, leads to an iOS app if this app is installed or to iTunes store if the app is not installed? If this URL exists, will it work well on computers (PCs and macs) and other terminals?

I think if I set up a web server myself, I could use JavaScript to check whether the target app is installed on the client device, but I don't want to do so if there is already a way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in deep link no need of web services or api,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik but the deep link only works when you've already installed the app, right?

Comment: yes, if already installed the app it redirect to the app otherwise the id is goes to the iTunes store

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I tried with the custom URL schemes, but it only works when you've already installed the app. Otherwise, the browser will complain that this URL scheme is not supported.

Comment: can u show ur detailed code or sent ur code in karthik.saral@gmail.com, i checked it up and tell to u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you cannot change the FB post message, or check whether a specific app is installed on your device using native code.

Therefore, I just take use of the URL to the iTunes store (See [How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)). When clicking the link, the behaviour depends on the OS version (seemingly). Sometimes, you're led to your app (if installed) and sometimes to the app store.