# Open AppStore through button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, app-store

Could you guys help me to translate the following code into Swift?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/de/app/x-gift/id839686104?mt=8&uo=4"]];
```

(or do I have to take this link: *itms://itunes.apple.com/app/id839686104*?)

Comment: [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I know this is not homework question, but you still need to show some effect.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Here. But I highly suggest you learn the basics of Swift!

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "itms://itunes.apple.com/de/app/x-gift/id839686104?mt=8&uo=4")!)
```

If you wanna open the AppStore in **Swift 5**:

```
if let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1629135515") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Comment: Does this effectively allow the user to "gift" the app to a third party? The `x-gift` reference?

Comment: Ha, X-Gift was my app's name @KatherineJenkins

Comment: is that "id" required or can I use the aped with digits only?

Comment: is it possible to open non store apps? like in house developed ones?

Comment: @Adam Yes this is possible via associated domains and deep linking. Let's say the app you're developing responds to a custom scheme mycoolapp://. This means if some other app calls openUrl on a URL with a scheme of "mycoolapp://" and your app exists on that device, the device will attempt to open that link with your app. How the link is handled is determined by your app.

Comment: FYI, this will open the *iTunes Store* app and not the *App Store* (then it should be `itms-apps://`)

Comment: what is `mt` and `uo` parameter for? Where can I find all parameters I can pass to the url?

Answer (score 74):

Swift 3 Syntax and improved with an 'if let'

```
if let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1024941703"),
UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

UPDATE 7/5/17 (Thank you Oscar for pointing this out):

```
if let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1024941703"),
    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
{
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, but openURL() is deprecated. Now we should use this one for the same behaviour 
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

Comment: You can also now add `{action=write-review}` to the url string - to jump directly to rating and writing the review...

Answer (score 20):

I use this combination, its better for rate/shopping.

(partially from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store/32008404#32008404))

```
    @IBAction func rateMe(sender: AnyObject) {
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        openStoreProductWithiTunesItemIdentifier("107698237252");
    } else {
        var url  = NSURL(string: "itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xxxxxxxxxxx/id107698237252?ls=1&mt=8")
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) == true  {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
        }

    }
}
func openStoreProductWithiTunesItemIdentifier(identifier: String) {
    let storeViewController = SKStoreProductViewController()
    storeViewController.delegate = self

    let parameters = [ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : identifier]
    storeViewController.loadProductWithParameters(parameters) { [weak self] (loaded, error) -> Void in
        if loaded {
            // Parent class of self is UIViewContorller
            self?.presentViewController(storeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
func productViewControllerDidFinish(viewController: SKStoreProductViewController) {
    viewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

don't forget to import and delegate:

```
import StoreKit

class RateMeViewController: UIViewController, SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate {
```

Comment: plus 1 for the StoreKit. It's a better way than just opening the AppStore

Comment: best answer for using StoreKit.

Answer (score 15):

Swift 4 with completion handler:

**Make sure to update your id in the appStoreUrlPath**

```
func openAppStore() {
    if let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id..."),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) { (opened) in
            if(opened){
                print("App Store Opened")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("Can't Open URL on Simulator")
    }
}
```

Comment: What `self.track()` does?

Comment: In this case I was calling my analytics provider to add a record that a user opened the app store.  But I just removed the line since it was unrelated.  Thanks for the question!

Answer (score 12):

**For Swift 5 (tested code) to open App Store link**

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/your-appName/id123456?mt=8") 
{
           if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
              UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
           }
           else {
                 if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
                }
           }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Since other answers didn't work for me (Swift, Xcode 6.1.1) here I post my solution:

```
var url  = NSURL(string: "itms://itunes.apple.com/de/app/x-gift/id839686104?mt=8&uo=4")

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5.0**:

import StoreKit

```
extension YourViewController: SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate {
    func openStoreProductWithiTunesItemIdentifier(_ identifier: String) {
        let storeViewController = SKStoreProductViewController()
        storeViewController.delegate = self

        let parameters = [ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : identifier]
        storeViewController.loadProduct(withParameters: parameters) { [weak self] (loaded, error) -> Void in
            if loaded {
                self?.present(storeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    private func productViewControllerDidFinish(viewController: SKStoreProductViewController) {
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// How to use

openStoreProductWithiTunesItemIdentifier("12345")
```

Comment: what is identifier string ?

Comment: @YogeshPatel Its the app ID from the app url, say below is the url then app id would be 123456789 https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id123456789

Answer (score 4):

> Check newer app update available on iTunes in Swift 3

```
let currentAppVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary
Alamofire.request("http://itunes.apple.com/jp/lookup/?id=548615", method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
        if let value = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let versionNum = value["results"]?.value(forKey: "version") as? NSArray
            if versionNum?[0] as! String != currentAppVersion?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String {
                self.alertForUpdateApp()
            }
        }
    }

func alertForUpdateApp() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Update Available", message: "There is a newer version of this app available", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let alertActionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    let alertActionUpdate = UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        if let url = URL(string: Constants.API_REDIRECT_TO_ITUNES),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

        }
    })

    alertController.addAction(alertActionCancel)
    alertController.addAction(alertActionUpdate)

    let pushedViewControllers = (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers
    let presentedViewController = pushedViewControllers[pushedViewControllers.count - 1]

    presentedViewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: i need to open my app store of my iphone..by pressing rate me button in my app. so that i need to open my app in app store itself in my iphone...how can i do with ur code..here my post...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499611/trigger-app-store-to-open-in-mobile-to-open-particular-app?noredirect=1#comment75992581_44499611

Comment: You should integrate this code:  if let url = URL(string: Constants.API_REDIRECT_TO_ITUNES),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

        }

Comment: use this url instead of Constants.API_REDIRECT_TO_ITUNES:  "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/your-appName/id548615579?mt=8"

Comment: but does this code will trigger the app store to open or any browser to open...because i need an  app store app to open and show the app

Comment: It will open the app store app.

Comment: i tried `  if let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/Spending Tracker/id548615579?mt=8"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){ if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            } }`  but its open in safari page

Comment: but in my case its open app store

Comment: does my code correct : `if let url = URL(string: "itunes.apple.com/in/app/Spending Tracker/id548615579?mt=8"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){ if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil) } else { // Fallback on earlier versions } }`

Comment: There is no issue in your code I think you running this in simulator. If you run app on iPhone it will open app store link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146488/discussion-between-raj-joshi-and-hybrid-dev).

Comment: i tried this cide again `@IBAction func rateNowButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    
      print("Rate now button pressed")
        
        if let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/Spending Tracker/id548615579?mt=8"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){ if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
             print("inside function to open appa store")
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
          
             print("it's failed")
            } }  
    }
`

Comment: but i put some print function to check.. but its printing only `Rate now button pressed`..its not going inside that method...

Comment: I'd like to mention that the iTunes lookup can have caching issues, meaning that it won't always return you the latest version. One way to prevent this is to clear the cache before the call: `URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open in app store use

```
 let appstoreUrl =  "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/myapp-test/id11111111?mt=8"
 UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: appstoreUrl)!)
```

if you want in itune store use

```
  let ituneUrl =  "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/in/app/myapp-test/id11111111?mt=8"
 UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: ituneUrl)!)
```

Answer (score 3):

In **Swift 4.2** and **Xcode 10.2**

You have two ways to open **App Store** or **iTunes Store**

If you want to open App Store use **https** or if you want to open iTunes Store use **itms**

Ex: https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/yourAppName/id14****4?mt=8 //For App Store

itms://itunes.apple.com/in/app/yourAppName/id14****4?mt=8 //For iTunes Store

**Method 1:** This is simple direct and old approach

```
let url  = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/smsdaddy/id1450172544?mt=8")//itms   https
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url! as URL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url! as URL)
    }
```

**Method 2:** New approach

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/smsdaddy/id1450172544?ls=1&mt=8") {
   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
       UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
   } else {
       // Earlier versions
       if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
          UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

SwiftUI

```
import StoreKit

struct StoreView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let appID: String
 
     
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<StoreView>) -> SKStoreProductViewController {
        let sKStoreProductViewController = SKStoreProductViewController()
        let parameters = [ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : appID]
        sKStoreProductViewController.loadProduct(withParameters: parameters)
        return sKStoreProductViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SKStoreProductViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<StoreView>) {

    }

}
```

//how to use

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showAppAtStore){
StoreView(appID: "12345678") 
}
```

Comment: if you want to do this to update your own app, however, this fails in some versions of iOS since the app cannot be updated while loaded. Pity.

Comment: this will fail -`SKStoreProductViewController` can't be embeded; u will receive assertion crash with SwiftUI

Answer (score 2):

For the new AppStore, simply open your app's link on AppStore and replace the `https` scheme to `itms-apps` scheme.
Example on Swift 4:

```
if let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-app/id12345678?ls=1&mt=8") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

You can find your app's link on the App Information page.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

```
let url = "your app url"
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
 } 
else {
    // Earlier versions 
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### For those looking for the updated working solution

Most of the given solutions here are outdated & deprecated, like "canOpenURL", "openURL" etc.

```swift
let appStoreLink = "https://apps.apple.com/app/{app-name}/{app-id}"

guard let url = URL(string: appStoreLink) else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

Comment: This is the old-fashioned not-updated solution, that doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var url  = NSURL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1024941703")
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) == true  {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
    }
```

Xcode 6.4

Comment: This is identical to the above answer but with a different URL.

Answer (score 1):

For me didn't worked one of this answers. (Swift 4) The app always opened the iTunes Store not the AppStore.

I had to change the url to "http://appstore.com/%Appname%" as described at this apple Q&A: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1633/_index.html

for example like this

```
private let APPSTORE_URL = "https://appstore.com/keynote"
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: self.APPSTORE_URL)!)
```

(remove spaces from the app-name)

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions (iOS 15+) of SwiftUI you could do something like this:

```
Link("To App Store", destination: URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com")!)
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent) // <-- iOS 15+ only
```

And if you want to be sure the URL is valid:

```
if let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com"), 
             UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                    Link("To App Store", destination: url)
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 2024 era, if using old-fashioned storyboards:

Save you typing:

```
@IBAction func tapOpenAppStore() {
    if let u = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com"),
      UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(u) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(u)
    }
}
```

Note, simulators have no app store. It does nothing (and does not crash or hiccup) if run on a simulator.