# trigger app store to open in mobile to open particular app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am working on swift 3 project. In that i have 3 button with my app names like below :

```
myntra app
skoda app
tyiuy app
```

So every thing will be as a button. so if i press`myntra app` app button or if i press that `myntra app` button then i need to open the app store app in our mobile to go to my `myntra app` page . Should i need the link. If yes with that link how can i trigger the app store in my app to open my particular app details in app store mobile .

```
Note : its an button click for all the 3 names
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: 1) Create a view controller and have web view in it 2) When a button is clicked, pass the App Store url 3) Load the passed url in web view. In this way you can show the App Store within app.

Comment: @pkc456  i dont want to use a browser or other web view. I need to open the iphone app store app..

Comment: If you want to open App Store app with dedicate app, then on button click write this:- `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/myntra-fashion-shopping-app/id907394059?mt=8")!)`