# How to get the link direct to my app like android?

Tags: ios

look i want to get the link direct to my app on iphone from the apple connect but i cant find any options to do it, i found testflight but i dont want testflight i want a link like android like this:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stellarclubs
```

but i want it in ios , when i click this link on my iphone it goes to my app for downloading.
i did not found any options in my apple connect.

i hope my question can be understood

thank you.

Comment: Here is the complete solution : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1629/_index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open AppStore through button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882936/open-appstore-through-button)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have released a production app: (If not, you won't have the below option)

Log into [appstoreconnect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/)

> Go to "My Apps" > Select App > Under App Store tab  and App Information, scroll all the way down to Additional Information and there will be a link for "View on App Store"