# What URL to use for sharing app on Facebook, twitter,...?

Tags: ios, facebook

I would like to include a button in my app "share this app'. And then I would popup the
standard UIActivityViewController. I would attach the URL to my app in the app store.
But what URL should I use? Are there any guidelines? I would like that it shows pretty on Facebook, twitter and stuff...

Comment: Facebook and Twitter both should parse the iTunes URL corectly and show a nice download this app view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the post mentioned by Andre Filoppio. It does indeed mention a lot of different URL that could potentially be used. I have been testen them all, the only one that got my nice pretty Facebook mention was:

http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXX (where XXXXX is your app id)

The fancy ones like http://appstore.com/ProductNameWithoutSpacesAndStuff

all have the same problem: they have so many redirects, or open in itunes directly, that Facebook just displays this kind of message "connecting to Itunes store" instead of your app icon with something like "available on the app store"

(sorry guys I had a nice picture, but apparently I don't have enough reputation to post this to this answer)

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate, already answered this question see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store) ..

But you need to have the app on the appstore already so yeah, or you need to be sure of your appname.

EDIT: 
Use itms:// instead of http:// for it to open directly in the appstore and not redirect from the browser first