# How to link an application to App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

Don't get this confused with the itunes linking. I know how to send a user to iTunes Store app with purple logo and that is not I want. I want to send the user to App Store app with blue logo.

> itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myappname/myappid

Already checked this post, didn't answer my question: [How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

Comment: There is no URL Scheme to the App Store there is only the URL Scheme to iTunes. Checkout https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html So that link you have provided probably provides the best possible answer since you can't open the App Store.

Comment: By the looks of it the Apple Documentation isn't up to date if `Gary Riches` answer works.

Answer (score 1):

The follow link sends someone to the App Store on iOS and allows them to review my app. Change the parameters and it will go to the App Store for your app:

[itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Bouncing+Ball+Games&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&id=926193671](http://itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Bouncing%20Ball%20Games&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&id=926193671)

Sample code to open within an app:

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Bouncing+Ball+Games&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&id=926193671";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

Comment: can you clarify which are the parameters that should be changed?