# Apple's latest (2015) 'link to app store' directive causes unwanted Safari behaviour

Tags: objective-c, iphone, hyperlink, app-store

I want to add a link from my app to another of my apps on the appstore. 
Question [How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store) showed that the itunes.apple.com link was,until recently, the normal way to go. I've tried this and everything is fine.  The problem begins when I disgard this and use Apple's new recommendation of using appstore.com. I use the following line of code:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@http://appstore.com/myappname"]];
```

The first time I call this from my app it works well. You see it jump through Safari and move onto the appstore where it displays my app.

At this point if you look back into Safari you will notice a new blank tab labelled Favourites has been created.

If I go back to my app and perform the same action to link to the appstore again I'm prompted with one of the two popup boxes:

**"Open this page in "App Store"?    [Cancel] or [Open].**

or

**"Cannot Open Page.   Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"  [OK]**

I've found that manually deleting the blank tab in Safari will allow the link to work properly but this behaviour isn't what I want my users to see- and I wouldn't be expecting them to delete the blank tabs from Safari.

Any advice on stopping this behaviour whilst following Apple's new rules greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is using an in-app store view acceptable, or you need to go out to the App Store?

Comment: @Wain.  I guess either option would be ok as long as the user is given the opportunity to buy my app from the view that has been opened. My preference is that my app issues some form of call to the app store but isn't owning it or waiting on it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and clean solution is to present an instance of `SKStoreProductViewController` inside your app (modally) to display information on the products you are interested in. The user can interact with it as a small view on the App Store and you can simply dismiss it when done.