# Send user to iOS9 app store to update

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

I would like to send a user to the iOS app store update page so they can update my app when prompted, so I can require that users update the app if the update contains critical security fixes, or something else vital.

I believe that I have found a link that I can send the user to the update page, which is

> itms-apps://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftwareUpdate?id=<appid>&mt=8

So in my case I would use

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(
    NSURL(
      string: "itms-apps://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftwareUpdate?id=969701501&mt=8"
    )!
)
```

But I am not able to test it, because I am given a 404 page in the app store when I try

[image: 404 page]

I'm assuming that I get this because the app was not actually downloaded from the app store (it was put onto my test device from Xcode), and I'm unable to test the link because I would need to download the application from the app store if my assumption is correct.

I've looked into using an [`itunes.apple.com`](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id969701501?mt=8) link, but that redirects 
to the app page, and although that page *does* have an update button, `phobos.apple.com` seems to be better because it only contains information about the update, and the new features in it, making it more user friendly.

Is my link correct for `iOS 9`, or is there a different/better method to send the user to the app store's *Update App* page? Even better, is there any way to prompt the user to update the app via an alert (kind of like requesting access to camera roll or location services, but updating the application)

Comment: iOS 9 is still in beta stage. Maybe you should wait till iOS 9.0 is finalized first.

Comment: @Raptor the title is misleading. The question reflects a different goal; simply guiding users to the App Store URL. Jojo, iOS 9 has nothing to do with the URL Apple gives you for your app (which is unique). Instead of doing what your doing you should go this route; see the discussion here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29456019 once users get there they will then be told if they meet requirements to download the app

Comment: @soulshined true, I think I understand you now. It's my fault for not clarifying. I'm trying to start the update once the user presses a button in the app (so once they tap `update` in the app, the app closes and starts updating). I'll update the question.

Comment: @Jojodmo true. And that definitely is a more clearly defined goal now. I haven't checked the APIs for iOS 9. But as far as <=iOS 8 devs don't have the ability to start downloads without sending them to the App Store first, and even if free, you won't be able to click a button on their behalf. But there could be something new in iOS 9 APIs.

Comment: @soulshined I did some research and it looks like it won't be able to automatically update without the user tapping the update button. But it seems like `phobos.apple.com` does have an advantage over `itunes.apple.com`, which is that the user can see what is included in the update instead of having to scroll down to the "whats new" tab which most users don't even know exists (I didn't even know until recently)

Comment: Yeah I use that all the time. I hate that you can't hide it after you tapped what's new. But that's actually a cool feature I wouldn't mind having as a dev. You should send a feature request to them to create a new framework for that. I've been bugging them about bringing back a direct like to the rate section for an app again. That's extremely useful for us and our brand.

Comment: Did you find a solution? The phobos link as you show (with my app's ID) returns a 404 for me even with my app installed. I can link directly to my app as suggested by Nilesh. But when an update is available the app store page shows an "Open" button, not an "Update" button. Users tapping Open are taken right back to the existing app. My SO question on this topic has gone unanswered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460124/how-to-link-to-update-page-for-our-app Maybe this is not possible?

Comment: @skypanther I would assume its not possible... I did make a feature request about 4 months ago and it hasnt been responded to. Currently, I have to use the itunes link

Comment: @Jojodmo Thanks. What I have implemented is linking to our company's list of apps rather than directly to the app itself. Since we have just one app, there's not too much confusion. Tap the one app listed and you get the download link. This won't work as well once we release additional apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this, you can open your application via the URL provided by Apple. This will automatically re-direct to your application page on App Store.

For example, https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ibooks/id364709193?mt=8

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sending the user to the app page - it's about forcing the user to update the app if the update contains a critical security fix or something else like that. To do that we need to send the user to the update page

Comment: Okay. Then in that case you need to implement your own logic. I have done that in one my app, In that I have created one database table at backend to store the current version of the application. Along with that I have stored one two flags like recommended & required. If I have to update the app required then i am setting required flag to 1. If that flag is one then I am re-directing user to application page on App Store. If its recommended then I am allowing user to use application with current version. hope this will clear your query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've already done the backend things, I'm trying to find out how to prompt the user to update the app. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I have displayed alert in the application based on above condition. If its required then user can't go ahead & user our application until he update the latest version. if required then user can go ahead & user it..

Comment: I am doing above thing on main/first page of the application... You can do at your required places...

Comment: I just clarified the question. I'm trying to force the user to update the app by sending them to the app store and automatically starting an update

Comment: If user have kept Automatic Update enabled in setting then it will be updated automatically. If you are re-directing the user to the App Store page then it will not be start updating automatically. User need to click on the update button to do that..

Comment: The problem is that if there's a critical fix, we can't wait for the automatic update.

Comment: Yes for that only, When user launch the app call you API & check the flag. If its required then re-direct them to App Store every time. This is the only way for you.

Comment: If you found any other way then please let me know, Else you can accept my answer if you think its proper..

Comment: Although it can kind of do what I'm looking for, I'm looking for a more user-friendly way to display the update information (one that only includes what's new, and nothing else). You can read the updated question for more info