# swift open link in safari/app store

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, app-store

I have a simple iOS app and I'm in the process of developing a pro version of the app. I will then add a hyperlink to the existing app that will point to the url of the pro app in the app store. So is there any recommended way to do this so when the user taps the link, they will be forwarded to the pro app's page on the app store?

Will the user be redirected to the app store if I simply use this piece of code?

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL("http://itunes.apple.com/myappname")
```

Comment: See this question for the possibilities of App Store redirection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store

Answer (score 2):

As Far As I know, there's no longer

```
itms-apps://
```

instead of the regular http://

so the best way is to use this line of code, watch that I've put it in NSURL because you can't past a simple String. Other than that you can use ! at the end or better way is to use IF LET ...

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/24-s-wt-h-plyqzyh-hyhydh-smqry/id897282272?ls=1&mt=8")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/developerName")!)
```

With this one I couldn't open my app page on the App Store then I went to my iTunes page on Safari, copied my home page uri and pasted it to related code. And it works perfect!

Just copy your iTunes page on the internet and paste it!