# Open Clock app programmatically in Objective c (Not Device Settings)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, url-scheme

I need to open iOS system Clock app from my application. It's easy to open app settings using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

But i need to open clock app exactly. Does it really work ? If yes, then how. I tried with these, nothing works:

[image]

In Source :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"clock-alarm:"]]
```

Comment: Follow this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935987/open-url-schemes-in-ios/41955824#41955824

Comment: So how i can open this boss ? @ meaning-matters

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: On,y the URL schemes documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) are available. Any other URL schemes that may exist should be considered as private APIs

Comment: It's not possible using non-private APIs, and possibly not without root access (Jailbreak).