# In my own app i want update button to show if there is updated version of that app is on app store

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

In my own app i want update button to show if there is updated version of that app is on app store.if there is then i want to navigate the user to that update app location. is that possible to do

Answer (score 0):

App version may be received via [iTunes Search API](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html). For example, you can request a json that contains your app version by bundle id with url like this https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.yelp.yelpiphone
 and after receiving an answer, you can find a version parameter.
Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2337601/1254172) for info on navigation to app location.

Comment: The App Store website is not the same the App Store app, is it.

Comment: itms:// links will be handled by appstore app as well

Comment: But that still doesn't take you to the *update* section of the App Store app.

Comment: but the app may be updated from the app page. there is no way to open appstore update page isnt' it?

Comment: I don't believe so, no.  I don't think Apple want you doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Exactly. So opening an app's page will be the best solution to OP's question, i think. This is not against apples guidelines.