# WeChat does not redirect to iTunes app store on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, itunes-store, wechat

So I have a website with functional redirects to both the Google play store and the itunes store.  Using the WeChat messaging application I can open an in-app browser to view the webpage and do everything I normally would.

The problem surfaces when using WeChat on an iPhone.  I can see both links and click on either of them, but the itunes link does redirect as desired.  Keep in mind that this is not a problem on Android, both links redirect properly inside the app on my Android phone.

The goal is to have the button open up the actual itunes store app, and not link to the itunes webpage but even using `itms` `itms-apps` the connection doesn't go through.  On said iPhone in Safari and Chrome, these buttons link properly.  It is only in WeChat that the itunes  redirect button does not work.

I've tried adding an additional page that the button redirects to, which is 
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myapp/myappid'" />` but it just loads the blank the page and freezes because of the failure to redirect.  In fact, simply trying to load `http://itunes.apple.com` in the app results in failure.

Perusing StackOverflow I found  [this post about linking to the app-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store) but none of the answers really helped.

So I'm hoping some one has some idea of what to do or has some experience with a workaround for a situation like this since WeChat is integral to my app's performance.

**Update:**

I still haven't found a solution to my problem, but I've managed to get a lead.  The only link to iTunes that works in *any* way is http://mzstatic.com, but the problem is that I can't seem to find the proper parameters to link to an app.  Everything that I've seen online seems to show using the link to grab images.

Comment: don't put the url in quotes. `url=http...`, not `url='http...''

Comment: Like I said everything already works on other systems.  Any attempt to link to appstore or itunes/apps fails in WeChat.

Comment: Have you found any way to open itunes link in wechat?

Comment: No, it seems to be a restriction placed by either iTunes or WeChat.  I had to move on to other projects and was never able to find a solution.

Comment: check this [issue](https://github.com/hoosin/mobile-web-favorites/issues/7)

Comment: I can't read Chinese and the Google translate isn't really helping for @jayxhj conmment.  If anyone can read this and translate it into an answer I'll happily accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

check this [issue](https://github.com/hoosin/mobile-web-favorites/issues/7)

1. Guiding your user to scan QR code , you can generate your QR code by using this [service](http://scanova.io/design-qr-code-generator.html#/create/appstore) , adding your **appsto** url to the QR code (open App Store , find your app , click share , click copy link , you can get your app redirect url offered by Apple);
2. Register your mobile application on Tencent's Application Treasure,click the **Micro Download** to apply for you app , add your app store url to generate your **Micro Download url** which will redirect to app store , the offical document are here [mobile application access](http://wiki.open.qq.com/index.php?title=mobile/%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8%E5%AE%9D%E5%BE%AE%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD)

so , have a try , hope it helps.