# email link that opens mobile app is installed

Tags: android, ios, mobile-application

I need a way to include a link in an email which either opens a mobile app or redirects the user to a website depending on whether the mobile app is installed or not. I need a solution for both Android and IOS, it is there a set practice on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a combo of answers here I think.

For iOS, You can replace http:// with itms:// or itms-apps:// to avoid redirects.

[How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

For Android, I think you'll want to look at the `<intent-filter>` element of your Mainfest file. Specifically, take a look at the documentation for the `<data>` sub-element.

[Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you need to handle this via Intent Filter:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.permutassep.IntentEvaluator"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="your/url"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="your/url"
                android:scheme="https" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And the class you need to handle the intent data should look like this:

```
public class IntentEvaluator extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = null;

        if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getData() != null){
         // Do whatever you want with the Intent data.

        }
    }
}
```

Taken from an app I developed: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lalongooo/permutas-sep/master/app/src/main/java/com/permutassep/IntentEvaluator.java