# How can I display the contents of an App Store search in my app using Swift

Tags: swift, app-store, ios9

My goal is to display a table to the user with a list of all of my applications for cross-promotion. I have considered adding my applications (icons, names, descriptions) to a database on my website and accessing the data over the Internet, but I'd rather be able to directly query the App Store. The reasoning is that I will not have up manually update my database each time an update with a new logo is released or a new app released.
Is this possible? A search including only my other apps where I can display the information in a table view. Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Furthermore, I have seen ads that link to the app store. When you click on it, an app store scene pops up with a link to download it, but without switching to the actual App Store app. Does this happen automatically through iOS when you link to a specific app, or is this done through code that we write.

Comment: The iTunes rss generator would be a good place to start https://itunes.apple.com/rss/generator/ but you might also want to check the app store review guidelines and the rules on building apps using 3rd party data before you start building anything https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: Unfortunately the itunes rss generator doesn't allow search queries, it only offers a drop down box with options like "top games" :/ But an rss feed would be a lot like what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to link to an app or business's apps: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html

Use this to open app store links without leaving the application that is already open:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/index.html

This was also helpful:
[How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)