# Is it possible to have the ability to let customers purchase streaming content from itunes from within your ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, itunes, itunes-store

I wanted to add a feature to my app that allows you to purchase content from itunes from within the app.  Is this possible, and if it is does Apple give some type of reference fee for finding customers to purchase the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SKStoreProductViewController`. You specify the product's iTunes id to display that product. If you are part of the [Affiliate program](https://apple.com/itunes/affiliates), you can also specify your affiliate id to get a commission.

See the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32008404/1226963) for an example of using `SKStoreProductViewController`. You would need to add the use of the `SKStoreProductParameterAffiliateToken` key to add your affiliate id.