# Xcode 7 Swift 2 Prompt user to rate your iOS app within your app

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I've seen many posts on prompting/alerting user to rate the app within the app. As I understood, Apple will only allow users to rate it within App Store.

Now in my app, I would like to have a button to rate my app. When you click the button, it should take the user to App Store and directly to my app Page.

How I can create the link to my App in App Store when I've not yet uploaded my app in App Store. How will I know to direct the link to my App in App Store?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the app identifier number that is attached to your app that you see in your iTunes developer account. It will not be a live URL until your app is published. More information here:

[How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

The button itself should have an action function that opens a browser, like so:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "<YOUR_APP_URL>"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll check on this.