# Is it possible to to deep link through IOS or Android stores (pass data from url to app install)

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking

I am wondering if it is possible to send out a URL link to download and install an app from the IOS or Android app store and have the app open to a particular page. IE pass the data somehow from the URL the app during install.

Thanks

Comment: This thread might help you for iOS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know about Firebase Dynamic Links? I think it is exactly what you are searching for, see here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Answer (score 2):

I realise that I answered something else than was asked, but I'll leave the answer if by some odd case someone will be able to use my answer.

**For iOS:**
First you must register your custom URL scheme. I can recommend following [this tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html). 
A for handling the incoming URL there might be a better way, but I simply implement `func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool` in `AppDelegate.swift` and then do a string split (or whatever fits the URL you're expecting), and construct my navigation stack according. 
Ex:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
        if url.absoluteString.contains("/messages") {
            let myIntroViewController = navigationController!.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Intro") as! IntroViewController
            let messagesViewController = navigationController!.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Messages") as! MessagesViewController

            navigationController.viewControllers = [myIntroViewController, messagesViewController]
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try branch SDK. Please follow this link

https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: Firebase is a good all-in-one platform for smaller apps, especially if there are no plans to grow into additional functionality down the road. Firebase Dynamic Links will do what you want, but Branch links do all of the same things plus a great deal more. We have a comparison chart [here](https://blog.branch.io/firebase-dynamic-links-vs-branch-links-a-comparison)