# How to link Cordova app to App Store?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How can I create a link button in my cordova app, which is redirecting to my app on iOS/Android/Amazon App Store depending on the device?

I have tried the following code, it gets in the iOS if clause, but it doesn't redirect me, neither gives an error:

```
if(window.cordova && window.device) {
    if (device.platform.toUpperCase() === 'IOS') {
        window.open("https://itunes.apple.com/gb/[OBFUSCATED]");
    } else if (device.platform.toUpperCase() === 'ANDROID') {
        window.open("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=[OBFUSCATED]");
    } else {
        window.open("https://www.amazon.co.uk/[OBFUSCATED]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Only next helped to me in 2020: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587421/ionic-how-to-open-play-store-application-detail-page-from-javascript/63905554#63905554

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
IOS: itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/[appId]
Android: market://details?id=[appPackageId]
Amazon: amzn://apps/android?p=[appPackageId]
```

Comment: The android link worked for me. But for iOS I followed this link method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2337601/

Comment: Note, these don't work on the simulators but they work on the device.

Answer (score 5):

you can use [Inappbrowser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser).

Install inappbrowser plugin with following command:

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

and use following in your code:

```
  var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i) ? true : false;
    var isIOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/(ipod|ipad|iphone)/i) ? true : false;

if(isIOS){
        window.open("https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/[OBFUSCATED]","_system");
    } else if (isAndroid) {
        window.open("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=[OBFUSCATED]", "_system");
    } else {
        window.open("https://www.amazon.co.uk/[OBFUSCATED]", "_system");
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Ping comment if you stuck anywhere.

Comment: Hi Naitlik, my code is properly detecting the device type, however window.open is not working as i don't get redirected to anything. I did also try with "_system".

Comment: It workd for IOS after putting "itms-apps" instead of "https". Any idea how/if it needs to be changed for android/amazon stores?

Comment: "_system" works for both Android and IOS. Thanks @Naitik

Comment: Glad it's help @Arshad