# IONIC - How to open Application's feedback page in Play Store from Application using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-play

In my Ionic Application, I need to open my other application link in Play store.

I have tried following so far :

```
window.open('market://details?id=com.myapp.something', '_self')
```

And

```
window.open('market://details?id=com.myapp.something', '_system', 'location=no');
```

Above links opens in InnAppBrowser, I need them to open in playstore itself.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found that you can open it in your system Browser with **Package ID** and it will automatically redirect you to respective application store.

> $window.open("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your-app-package-name&hl=en","_system");

This worked for me the best.

**EDIT :**

There is a plugin available which might help : [Launch Review](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/launch-review)

Answer (score 3):

**Redirect IONIC application to play store**

```
window.open("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.carClient.bookMyDreamCar","_system");
```

**open playstore in your application**

```
window.location.assign('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.carClient.bookMyDreamCar')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open market apps for rating reviews then will be better to use this plugin instead

Ionic V3: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/launch-review/

Ionic >= V4: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/launch-review

It has in app review for ios >10.3 (higher changes to get a review) and simply opens google play market for android.

Dependency injection:

```
import { LaunchReview } from '@ionic-native/launch-review';

constructor( 
    private _platform: Platform,
    private _launchReview: LaunchReview
) { }
```

Implementation:

```
appId = null;
if (this._platform.is('android')) {
    appID = '_COM.ANDROID.PACKAGE.NAME_';
} else if (this._platform.is('ios')) {
    appID = '_APPLEID_';
}

if (appID) {
    if (this._launchReview.isRatingSupported()) {
        // For iOS > 10.3
        this._launchReview.rating().then((result) => {
            alert(result);
        });
     } else {
        this._launchReview.launch(appID);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**2020 Answer. Ionic 4.**

Only `window.location.assign` helped for me. Working both iOS and Android. iOS URL should be `itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/${iosITunesAppId}`, Android one `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=${packageName}`. `packageName` can be obtained using `cordova-plugin-app-version` plugin.

UPD: looks as I found why methods like `window.open('market://details?id=com.myapp.something', '_system');` didn't work for me. Looks as they require `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` plugin to be installed. I haven't that plugin installed in my app so that method didn't work.